# SQLPS equivalent to SqlServer Get-SqlServer?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlps

I currently am working with a script that utilizes the SQLPS module. This is due to the current version of my PowerShell, 4.0. I have a script that works on a coworkers machine, but not mine, that utilizes the SqlServer module, specifically the cmdlets `Get-SqlServer` and `Get-SqlDatabase`.

While I have seen that there is a `Get-SqlDatabase` cmdlet in the SQLPS module, I am unsure of what command will accomplish the same for me as the SqlServer command `Get-SqlServer`.

Does anyone know how I could convert the code to work with SQLPS?

```
@{ login = $_ ; server = Get-SqlServer $_.name $_.user $_.pass }
```

Hopefully that is enough information.